# What the color of methods means in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

[image]

What's the difference between those 'purple' methods and 'green' methods? I've checked IDE settings throughout but in vain, really confusing...

Comment: Looks like software bug I suppose.

Comment: i think its probably your settings,
check this  [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html?search=color#d32042e268)

Comment: @AhmedSunny Thanks, green stands for common methods while purple stands for magic methods, so it is a bug without doubt :D

Answer (score 1):

That is a IDE bug that is not able to recognize methods of the `Blueprint`. Green should stand for a method of a class while purple indicates a `property` of a class (e.g. `public $property` inside a `Class`).

Comment: yup, there are several issues with coloring at this moment (e.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-28835 & https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-36140). You can submit your full code sample to JetBrains tracker for investigation at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI#newissue=yes